# Como deixar parametro opcional, API asp.net core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma duvida em como deixar parametros opcionais na chamada do metodo na API.

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
[HttpGet("{aplicativoId}/{moduloId}/{taxaId}/{musicaId}/{produtoId}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<AppDto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppDto>>> GetAsync()
{
       
    var apps = await _testHandler.GetAsync(aplicativoId);
    return Ok(apps);
}
```

Como faço para deixar todos opcionais? No caso, se eu passar os 5 valores, o metodo traga o get dos 5 valores, se eu passar 4 traga somente ate o musicaId, se passar 3 somente até o taxaId e assim sucessivamente, tem alguma forma ?

Answer (score 0):

Para criar um parâmetro opcional no template de uma rota, basta colocar um ponto de interrogação no final do parâmetro, exemplo:

```
[HttpGet("{aplicativoId?}")]
```

Porém, ao criarmos rotas mais complexas, os parâmetros opcionais devem sempre serem os últimos parâmetros da rota, para que o ASP .NET possa corretamente identificar sua rota.

No seu exemplo, já que todos os parâmetros são opcionais, eu moveria todos para dentro do seu método GetAsync, preservando a sua rota independente dos parâmetros opcionais:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppDto>>> GetAsync(int aplicativoId, int moduloId, int taxaId, int musicaId, int produtoId)
```

Porém uma variável do tipo int nunca poderá ser zero, e seu valor padrão sempre é 0, portanto, você pode fazer a seguinte verificação no controller:

```
if (aplicativoId > 0 && moduloId > 0)
{
   var apps = await _testHandler.getAsync(aplicativoId,moduloId)
}
```

Comment: mas dessa forma ao executar via swagger nao vao aparecer os campos opcionais para a pessoa pssar valor ou nao para testar a api

Comment: Se eu passar tudo no GetAsync eles ficam todos como opcionais, os 2 primeiros sao obrigatorios

Answer (score -1):

Existem várias maneiras de conseguir isso
Seguindo a sua ideia incial, basta adicionar um "?" depois de cada parâmetro opcional
Exemplo com os dois primeiros parâmetros sendo obrigatórios e os demais opcionais:

```
[HttpGet("{aplicativoId}/{moduloId}/{taxaId?}/{musicaId?}/{produtoId?}")]
```

Você também pode limitar o tipo de cada parâmetro adicionando um ":" seguido do tipo desejado

```
[HttpGet("{aplicativoId:int}/{moduloId:int}/{taxaId:int?}/{musicaId:int?}/{produtoId:int?}")]
```

No GetAsync você pode obter os parâmetros na assinatura do método desta forma:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppDto>>> GetAsync(int aplicativoId, int moduloId, int? taxaId, int? musicaId, int? produtoId) {
   if(produtoId.HasValue) {
      // os 5 parâmetros foram passados
   }
   else if(musicaId.HasValue) {
      // apenas 4 parâmetros foram passados
   }
   else if(taxaId.HasValue) {
      // apenas 3 parâmetros foram passados
   }
   else {
      // apenas 2 parâmetros foram passados
   }
   ...
}
```

Você também pode criar uma classe contendo esses parâmetros e obter um objeto complexo no GetAsync utilizando [FromRoute]

Importante:
Depois do primeiro parâmetro opcional, todos os demais devem ser também opcionais

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).